# Momentum factor (mom) weekly

Tags: technical-analysis, momentum

I'm writing my dissertation about mutual fund performance and I can't find the weekly (Mom) factor. If there is a formula to transform monthly to weekly, I thought I would ask here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is most often simply calculated based on monthly returns with a 12 month lookback and excluding the most recent month (ie, 11-1).  There's no formula to 'transform' monthly momentum to weekly, but provided you have the underlying returns it's easy enough to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: Thanks Chris , I find a formula that someone used to transform to weekly 
   Factor weekly=(Π(Factor daily/100+1)i∈day-1)×100

Comment: If my response was helpful, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Chris' answer is in line with the underlying literature from "Returns to Buying Winners and Selling Losers: Implications for Stock Market Efficiency
" : https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1993.tb04702.x

Comment: @Dan, that would get you from daily data to weekly, but that wasn't what you asked about.